# Changing GIMP 2 installation folder on Windows

Tags: gimp

I've just installed GIMP 2.8.16 on Windows XP (32-bit). The installer prompted me for everything -- which components to install, file associations, etc. -- except for the installation folder (which it selently selected to be `%ProgramFiles%\GIMP 2`).

How do I install GIMP into the different folder? It occupies ~400 MB, and I'm running low on disk space on my `C:` drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strangely, once I've uninstalled GIMP and re-ran the installer, it *did* allow me to select a folder during the second run.

I'm not sure whether this is an intermittent bug or intended behaviour though.

Comment: If you had installed GIMP before, it will use the same folder you have used then. This is done to prevent users from accidentally installing two copies alongside each other and running the wrong one. Yeah, some users might actually want to do this, but the person who creates the installers got fed up with support requests from the many who don't...

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher: Indeed, I didn't notice in the first place I already *had* GIMP installed, so what I thought of as an *initial installation* was an *upgrade* instead.

Answer (score 8):

At least with the GIMP 2.10.x installer, using CMD to do `gimp-<VERSION>-setup.exe /?` revealed that the installer can be started with an install-directory pre-defined. Presumably this is for people who are doing regression-testing or such and want multiple versions, but this can also solve your issue.

For the installer I just downloaded, this worked for me, which I typed into CMD after `cd /d`ing to the folder where I downloaded the installer-file:

```
gimp-<VERSION>-setup.exe "/DIR=C:\Program Files\GIMP 2.10"
```

In my case, it was trying to install to "GIMP 2.8", which was not what I wanted, especially since I was trying to install 2.10.x and the name would have been misleading.

Comment: This is the answer. It worked for mas of the date of the comment.

Comment: Steve from the future here (May 2023), just updating to 2.10.34, and the installer still does not allow you to change the install directory in the GUI, but the /DIR arg still works perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

On GIMP 2.8.22 at least, the "Customize" button is on the bottom left of the installer:

[image]

Easy to miss.

Comment: **Future users:** this answer doesn't seem to work in case of installers for GIMP 2.10.x (and probably earlier) if you're trying to install multiple versions or if GIMP thinks you're trying to upgrade from a defunct installation-directory. If that describes you, please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [GIMP portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/gimp_portable), and copy it into another folder on a different partition.

Comment: Thanks, but I do want a complete installer. I'm truly amazed modern installers give me no freedom where I would expect a choice available.

Comment: @Bass You could re-pack the installer

Comment: @Bass, installing is a matter of just copying files. you could move your gimp directory to another drive(provided that it is permissible)\

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, with *no* Gimp installed.

I had Gimp on another drive, which I removed. The installer was still thinking Gimp is installed. I had to open Uninstall applications in control panel and find Gimp (which had default Windows icon... not the Gimp icon). I clicked <kbd>uninstall</kbd> and an error appeared messaging that Gimp could not be found. It also asked, do I want to remove it from apps list, so I clicked yes - and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I was just mindlessly clicking to install GiMP for ALL users. Once I selected "Install just for me" and then chose the custom install it allowed me to select a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Method provided by "Seldom 'Where's Monica' Needy" worked for me with little changing:
I have to crate new folder on C: drive and install Gimp there. Installing in Program Files was prohibited for some reason.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I run into the same mess as you guys, today!

You just need to clean the old one. Then reinstall, and select custom installation icon that located at the lower left corner. Good Luck!

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.